# how to show a map is well defined and isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

[image: from hungerford 3rd ed abstract algebra chatper 3.3]

It's my first time learning abstract algebra and I am really struggling even to begin this problem. What would be a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

a) You need to prove that the function is well defined, so take $[a]_{mn}=[b]_{mn}\in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$, this means $mn|a-b$ so $m|a-b$ and $n|a-b$, in other words

$$[a-b]_m=[0]\Rightarrow [a]_m=[b]_m$$

Analogously $[a]_n=[b]_m$, so $f([a]_{mn})=([a]_m,[a]_n)=([b]_m,[b]_n)=f([b]_{mn})$ , then f is well defined.

b) It is easy to see that $f$ is a homomorphism from the properties of modular arithmetic. Now we need to see that f is injective and surjective. Suppose given $[a]_{mn},[b]_{mn}\in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ such that $([a]_m,[a]_n)=([b]_m,[b]_n)$, then $m|a-b$ and $n|a-b$, sice $(m,n)=1$, then this implies that $mn|a-b$ then $[a-b]_{mn}=[0]_{mn}$ and so $[a]_{mn}=[b]_{mn}$ i.e f is injective.

We only need to see that $f$ is surjective. For that take an element $([a]_m,[b]_n)\in \mathbb{Z}_m\times \mathbb{Z}_m$.  From the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since $(m,n)=1$ the system:

\begin{align}
  x &\equiv a \mod m\\
  x &\equiv b \mod n
\end{align}

It has a solution mod $mn$, denote that solution by $[x]_{mn}\in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$, so we have $f([x]_{mn})=([a]_m, [b]_n)$ and then f is surjective. We conclude that f is an isomorphism.